# How to obtain the predictions of SVM model on single input?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, svm

So, I am trying to build a Spam detection model. It is trained on a dataset consisting of about 3500 messages. I used SVM to build a model. But, if I now wish to find out whether a message is spam or not for a single line of input message, how would I do it? I tried

`testmessage = ['Discount ! Free ! guarantee']
x = vectorizer.transform(testmessage)
y = svm.predict(x)`

But I am getting some error like :

> ValueError: X.shape[1] = 6 should be equal to 8272, the number of
>   features at training time

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import nltk

data = pd.read_csv("/media/piyush/Disk/Code practice/SPAM_Detction/spam.csv",encoding ='latin-1')
data = data.drop(["Unnamed: 2","Unnamed: 3","Unnamed: 4"], axis = 1)

# data.loc[data.v1 == "spam", "v1"] = int(1)
# data.loc[data.v1 == "ham", "v1"] = int(0)


data = data.rename(columns = {'v1': 'label', 'v2': 'text'})

def message_lower(msg):
    msg = msg.lower()
    return msg

from nltk import stem
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stemmer = stem.SnowballStemmer('english')
stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english'))

def alternative_review_messages(msg):
    # converting messages to lowercase
    msg = msg.lower()
    # removing stopwords
    msg = [word for word in msg.split() if word not in stopwords]
    # using a stemmer
    msg = " ".join([stemmer.stem(word) for word in msg])
    return msg

data['text'] = data['text'].apply(message_lower)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =  train_test_split(data['text'],data['label'], test_size=0.1, random_state= 1)
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)


from sklearn.svm import SVC
svm = SVC(C = 3000)
svm.fit(X_train,y_train)
X_test = vectorizer.transform((X_test)) y_pred = svm.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix 

print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))
```

Comment: On which of the three lines of the code does the error occur? The last one? What is the result of `print(x.shape)`?

Comment: @André it occurs on the last line. I don't know how but now it is working! I am getting an output.